# node.js 0.12 and grunt-contrib-connect - error calling setHeader()

Tags: node.js, grunt-contrib-connect

I am using grunt-contrib-connect for serving my app in development, and after upgrading to node.js 0.12 I started getting errors when trying to browse my app:

```
Error: "name" and "value" are required for setHeader().
at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:333:11)
at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
at Object.module.exports.grunt.config.options.middleware.allowCors [as handle] (/Users/abc/app/grunt_tasks/connect.js:24:29)
at next (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Object.module.exports [as handle] (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect-livereload/index.js:84:5)
at next (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:190:15)
at Function.app.handle (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:198:3)
at Server.app (/Users/abc/app/node_modules/grunt-contrib-connect/node_modules/connect/lib/connect.js:65:37)
at Server.emit (events.js:110:17)
at HTTPParser.parserOnIncoming [as onIncoming] (_http_server.js:491:12)
```

Nothing else has changed except upgrading node. I tried updating to the latest version of grunt-contrib-connect, but I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looking at the trace, it appears that the error is occurring in the middleware that is being specified to connect, in the function `allowCors`. It is common to have a middleware function specified to set CORS access headers on a response. As part of this function it is typical to have the line:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
```

Which, as of node 0.12, will throw this error on requests where `req.headers.origin` is undefined.

It appears that in 0.12, a change was made that requires the value to exist, where previously it could be undefined. See the change: https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/979d0ca874df0383311ca06f154f6965074196ee

When using 0.12, when specifying this middleware function, one option would be simply add a check to see if `req.headers.origin` is defined before attempting to set the access headers on the response:

```
if (req.headers.origin) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version');
}
```